# broken package error while trying to install Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, python

I got this error of broken packages, how do I fix this?

```
Conflicts: libghc-yi-frontend-pango-prof:i386 but 0.13.7-1build3 is to be installed
 libghc-yi-frontend-pango-prof:i386 : Conflicts: libghc-yi-frontend-pango-prof but 0.13.7-1build3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: please show us `lsb_release -as` And 
`grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` by edding your question.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Ubuntu
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
18.04
bionic

Comment: Maybe duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository